# Is tension a conservative force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, string, conservative-field

Are forces such as tension (from an in extensible string), normal reaction, and applied force from us, non conservative forces? If so why?

I have read in few books that these forces are labeled as nonconservative, but most of the time they are internal and do zero work and thus mechanical energy of the system remains constant, shouldn't they be conservative?

Comment: Can you provide some of the books where you have seen this?

Comment: Sry but i dont have links of it, it was a from a coaching material

Comment: *Tension*, *normal*, and *applied* are words that describe a property of a force, not a force itself.  Tension can be conservative or not.   If an ideal spring provides a tension force, it is conservative.  Tension provided by a rope is not.

Answer (score 3):

First, the definition of conservative force is not "a force that does no work".

Second, you can always make your system large enough so that total mechanical energy is conserved for the system, so this cannot determine whether forces are conservative or not either. Internal vs. external is a subjective distinction, whereas conservative vs. nonconservative is an objective distinction.

Finally, tension, normal forces, etc. are tricky, since they do different things in different scenarios. You have to be more specific about the specific scenario to discuss those in more detail. But in general they are not conservative, as the work done by forces like these can depend on the the path taken, or how the same path is "traversed".

> consider a block man system, let the man pull the block towards left by a constant force say F, if another external source makes a round trip for the block, dosent it mean that the work done by the man is zero which implies it is conservative?

That's what I meant by it being tricky. Constant forces are conservative, and mathematically there isn't anything distinguishing the pulling force and an actual force that is always constant. However, in reality pulling is more complicated. You can pull more or less. You could pull the same object the same distance but faster, thus the work done by your pulling doesn't just depend on the end points of the path, i.e. the force isn't actually conservative. A "pulling force" isn't really a fundamental force (at least macroscopically), and it would be even weirder to say you are storing potential energy by pulling on the block.

I don't fully follow your logic about an additional external force. I think you need to clarify that point.

Comment: no i didnt mean that, i have few problems in understanding the concept of conservative and potential energy, consider a block man system, let the man pull the block towards left by a constant force say F, if another external source makes a round trip for the block, dosent it mean that the work done by the man is zero which implies it is conservative? sry for inconvenience but i have a problem here that any force we exert can be conservative

Comment: @Crazyphysicist See my edit

Comment: i meant that when we lift a block against gravity(here gravity is a internal force while we are being the external source) then the work done by us is stored in the form of PE in the field and when we release it the 'block+field+earth' system's PE is converted to KE, but my doubt is if the internal force(which can be produced by any source including us) is constant and unidirectional like Fi^(in +x direction) then it can also be a conservative force as well, since no matter how the block moves, its internal force is always in a particular direction and of constant magnitude

Comment: and work done by this force against a external source around a closed path is always zero, and thus it should have a PE term associated with it, dont you think?

Comment: "you can always make your system large enough so that total mechanical energy is conserved" What about thermal energy?   Do you include thermal energy as a type of mechanical energy?   (I do not, but perhaps the distinction is in the eye of the beholder.)

Comment: @Crazyphysicist Conservative doesn't mean there exists any closed path where the work done by the force is $0$. It has to be true for all closed paths. Contriving an example where it just works for one path isn't sufficient

Comment: @Aaron Stevens  thanks i got to know about it recently from other source, if my assumption was correct, then atleast 90% forces would become conservative in 1 dimesion, and besides i noticed something, normal( includes forces that we exert on bodies) and tension mostly come under non conservative forces and even though they are non dissipative they just follow the rules for non conservative forces

Answer (score -2):

First, you need to know how a conservative force is defined. A force is conservative if the work done by it is path independent.

Now coming to your doubt, according to the work-energy theorem,
$$
\text{work (done by all the forces} = \Delta\left(\text{kinetic energy}\right).
$$
If you know, potential energy is defined only for conservative forces so,
$$
\text{work (done by a conservative force)} = -\Delta U,
$$
the negative of the change in potential energy.

---

So, take an example where tension and gravity (conservative) is acting on a pendulum. Applying the work-energy theorem,
$$
\text{work (done by tension)} + \text{work (done by gravity)} = \mathrm{K.E.} \text{ (final)} - \mathrm{K.E.} \text{ (initial)}
\tag{1}
$$
which implies
\begin{align}
\text{work (gravity)} & = - \left( U\text{ (final)} - U \text{ (initial)}\right)
\\
\text{work (tension)} & = 0.
\end{align}
Putting these in $(1)$ we get
\begin{align}
\mathrm{K.E.} \text{ (final)} + U \text{ (final)} = \mathrm{K.E.} \text{ (initial)} + U \text{ (initial)},
\end{align}
i.e., mechanical energy is conserved. Now, if the tension had done work this equation would be invalid and the mechanical energy would not have been conserved.

Observe that even though gravity (conservative force) is doing work the total mechanical energy is conserved but if the tension had done any work the mechanical energy of the system wouldn't have been conserved. This equation of conservation of mechanical energy is only valid if the work done by tension is zero, and is invalid if tension starts doing any work, hence a non conservative force.

Comment: You should minimize the use of all-caps. That is the computer equivalent of shouting. For emphasis use single asterisks around the phrase for *italics* and double asterisks for **bold**.

Comment: This answer is basically incorrect, as it incorporates the answer (tension being conservative) into its basic assumptions.

Comment: I didn't get your argument....